# question on understanding "UserInfo user1 = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();"

Tags: java, casting

I am learning java, and studying the following example from sun.com.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UserInfo implements Serializable {
   String name = null;

   public UserInfo(String name) {
   this.name = name;
 }

 public void printInfo() {
    System.out.println("The name is: "+name);
 }
}




import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class ReadInfo {

public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("name.out");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    UserInfo user1 = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();
    UserInfo user2 = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();

    user1.printInfo();
    user2.printInfo();
    ois.close();
    fis.close();
 }
 }
```

I am having question regarding the ReadInfo.java. In specific, I do not know how to understand the code of line UserInfo user1 = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();  Especially, what is the functionality of  “UserInfo” in the parenthesis. What is the relationship between (UserInfo) and ols.readObject( ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Object is being read and the code is casting it to a UserInfo Object, as there is some knowledge by the code author that "name.out" contains serialized Objects of type UserInfo.

The [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) makes this very clear:

> The method readObject is used to read
>   an object from the stream. Java's safe
>   casting should be used to get the
>   desired type. In Java, strings and
>   arrays are objects and are treated as
>   objects during serialization. When
>   read they need to be cast to the
>   expected type.

Additionally you might want to read up on the [Java tutorial's section re: Casting Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 1):

> In specific, I do not know how to
>   understand the code of line UserInfo
>   user1 = (UserInfo) ois.readObject();
>   Especially, what is the functionality
>   of “UserInfo” in the parenthesis.

`ObjectInputStream.readObject()` returns `Object`, not `UserInfo`, so it has to be casted to `UserInfo`